# The following web applications were stopped, but their classes from previous runs are still loaded in memory, thus causing a memory leak

Tags: java, tomcat, memory-leaks, blockingqueue

The method in schedule sometimes works sometimes. I'm running the ffmpeg code by using Blocking queue in the method. Tomcat warns when I find the leak button on the manager page. I m using Tomcat 8.5.6

> The following web applications were stopped (reloaded, undeployed), but their
>   classes from previous runs are still loaded in memory, thus causing a memory
>   leak (use a profiler to confirm):
>   /project-name
>   /project-name

Could this be the reason why the schedule sometimes doesn't work?

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more ?

Comment: @Scheduled annotation cron with spring boot created.
its task is to run ffmpeg. I'm running with ffmpeg builder with 4 thread with ArrayBlockingQueue. This cron sometimes works sometimes does not work. 
Tomcat, I got this warning. Could this have anything to do with this? Why sometimes does not work?